# My final function will not return

Tags: c

In my code I have a function at the very end that will not return any results. I think it might be an issue with my pointers. I am not sure what to do, I am new to coding, so any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int PrintInstructions(void);
void GetData(float*, float*, float*);
double AccelerationDisplacement(float vi, float t, float a);
void PrintOutput (double result, float vi, float t, float a);
int main(void) 
{
  int x=PrintInstructions();
  float vi,t,a;
  double result;
  GetData(&vi,&t,&a);
  AccelerationDisplacement;
  PrintOutput;
  return 0;
}
int PrintInstructions(void)
{
  printf ("This program determines distance traveled based on the data given, if you wish to quit, enter 'q', if you wish to continue enter any other character:");
  char leave;
  leave= getchar();
  if (leave == 'q' || leave == 'Q')
    exit(0);
  else 
    return 1;
}
void GetData (float* vi , float* t, float* a)
{
  printf ("Enter the vehicle's initial velocity in m/s:");
  scanf ("%f",&vi);
  printf ("Enter the time the vehicle travels in seconds:");
  scanf ("%f",&t);
  printf ("Enter the rate of acceleration in m/s:");
  scanf ("%f",&a); 

}
 double AccelerationDisplacement (float vi, float t, float a)
 {
   float d=(vi * t)+ (.5 * a) * (t * t);
   double result;
   d=result;
   printf ("Your answer is:", result);
  }
```

Comment: basically after the final scanf in GetData, the program ends.

Comment: `AccelerationDisplacement` lacks `return` statement. Assignment `d = result` looks backward.

Comment: even with the return statement, i get no text after the scanf. also flipping d and result still returns me with nothing.

Comment: If you want to call a function you need `()` and arguments. If you already have pointers you don't want the extra `&` on the scanf arguments either.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have enuf rep to comment directly under the question, I'm going to put it here. As [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) says,

1. you do not need the extra & in your scanf as you are already passing pointers as arguments (I suggest you spend some time understanding what & in scanf signifies)
2. AccelerationDisplacement and PrintOutput are functions. So, when you call them, you need to have () next to them and pass the relevant arguments in the same order as the declaration at the top -

   AccelerationDisplacement(vi, t, a);

   PrintOutput(vi, t, a);

As a piece of unsolicited advice, learn how to step through each line using tools like gdb for debugging. That will help a lot in understanding what the code is doing.

Comment: what is the tool gdb?

Comment: Here is the link to [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). 


Google (or any search engine) is your friend. Use it. Happy learning/coding.